# How to select (populate?) records from a field's value to another field's value in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database: PostgreSQL

I have this starting query with this starting result.

```
select 
plw.total_pages,
plw.page_range,
plw.from_page,
plw.to_page
from plw
where plw.id = 6
```

[image: result]

I want to get data from a query (I don't know if it can call it "populate"). There is only this one record in the database but I want to get total of `to_page` - `from_page` = 75 - 50 = 25 records as a result of the query. Each populated record should have another field `page` to track which page it is.

The result should be something like this:

| total_pages | page_range | from_page | to_page | page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | true | 50 | 75 | 50 |
| 100 | true | 50 | 75 | 51 |
| 100 | true | 50 | 75 | 52 |
| 100 | true | 50 | 75 | . . . |
| 100 | true | 50 | 75 | 73 |
| 100 | true | 50 | 75 | 74 |
| 100 | true | 50 | 75 | 75 |

Just so that I can get 25 records out of just 1 record within its page range.

Is there any solution to achieve this?

Comment: What's the database? You can use `generate_series()` if available.

Comment: @TheImpaler It is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the specific database so here are two solutions:

1. `generate_series()` is the typical function that produces rows in a range of numbers, and it's trivial to use, if available.

   ```
    select p.*, n.curr
    from plw p
    cross join generate_series(
      (select from_page from plw where id = 6),
      (select to_page from plw where id = 6)
    ) n (curr)
    where p.id = 6
   ```
2. The more generic way is to use a recursive CTE that can produce the rows you want. For example:

   ```
    with
    n (curr, ls) as (
      select from_page, to_page from plw where id = 6
     union all
      select curr + 1, ls from n where n < ls
    )
    select p.*, n.curr
    from plw p
    cross join n
    where p.id = 6
   ```

Comment: The database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: @holydragon You are in luck... both solutions apply. The first one is more performant in case you need to generate thousands of rows.